# Connection String for MySQL in Visual Studio

Tags: mysql, string, visual-studio-2012, connection

I already tried searching and reading posts and questions here, but I still cannot find the answer I need. Hope that someone can help me...

I'm working on Visual Studio 2012, and I'm trying to connect to a hosted database in MySQL, which uses phpMyAdmin.

I have an example here which is used to connect to a SQLServer database, which goes like this:

```
new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ecomerce.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
```

*(I know it's connecting to a local datatable, but that's not important)*

I believe I should find some different 'new' type to instantiate, in order to connect to a MySQL database, as ' new SQLConnection' is for SQLServer.
A friend told me I should use a 'MySQL Data Connection' from Oracle. I downloaded it and installed it, but really don't see any changes. What should I do? What I am supposed to do to connect to my database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple connection string for MySql is (in C#)

```
MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection("Server=myServerAddress;" + 
                                          "Database=myDataBase;" + 
                                          "Uid=myUsername;" + 
                                          "Pwd=myPassword;");
```

Of course you should add a reference to the MySql.Data.dll appropriate for your version of MySql and add a using statement to reference the namespace in your code.

Other examples of connectionstring variations could be found at [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

Comment: YES! that's exactly what I was looking for! but 'm not quite sure I'm understanding what you say later. How do I add this reference? and what statement should I include in the Namespace? I believe that's what left for me, as I cannot do a 'new MySqlConnection, because Visual Studio doesn't recognize that type of variable. however, I truly believe that, if I could make it recognize it, that connection string would be everything I need. Would you mind explaining me something of this, please? Thank you very much!

Comment: To use an external library (like MySql.Data.dll) in your NET application you need to add a reference to the library. [Here the MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wkze6zky(v=vs.110).aspx). After that, you could use the classes available in the library, but you need to prefix the names with the full namespace identifier. So you should type `MySql.Data.SqlClient.MySqlConnection = new...`. To avoid this lengthy typing for every class you add a line to the top of your code file `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;` and then type only the class name

Comment: Thank you! Really, thank you very much! that has just solve my problem! I could import this library, and changed all my webmethods that dealedwith connection from 'SQLConnection' type to 'MySqlConnection' type, and now everything works!

Answer (score 0):

```
    string strConn = @"Server=localhost;Database=Bancodados;Uid=root;Pwd='numsey';Connect Timeout=30;"; 

conn = new MySqlConnection(strConn);
```